# WCF listen base address anyip

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

i want my servicehost to have the base address of any IP 
so i tried this

```
new ServiceHost(typeof(LoggingController),new Uri("0.0.0.0"));
```

and it gives me invalid URI format

any one knows how should i write this ?

well i tried to access it from outside of my local lan and it didnt work , i made a small test software using tcpiplistener and i started listening to the same port and i set the base address of the tcpip protocol to anyip and the small test software worked so i figured out all i need to do is setting the same for the Webservice –

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,10021);
```

this works which also mean my system admin did his job of making sure the port/server is accessable from outside, now shouldnt my webservice work !? it work but i cant access it from outside , i can access it from the same pc if i run client on the same pc

Comment: actually i didnt know how to accept answers i thought all i have to do when i find answer helpful i click up on it !

Answer (score 4):

The following code works for me in a similar situation:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8080/MyService");
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServer), baseAddress);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of a problem we had with our software. The default configuration of the webservice used windows network credentials to apply message based security which - due to the domain/network credentials - won't work from another network. Our solution was to disable security on the service binding (which may be a bit tricky depending on the binding you use). For the default bindings like `WebHttpBinding` it's just passing a parameter in the constructor.
Hope this helps!

Comment: can you explain more what do you mean plz ?

Comment: what parameter i need to pass ?

Comment: nevermind i got it to work it was a server issue , thanks any way , i will up your answer though

Comment: For `WebHttpBinding` it's `WebHttpSecurityMode.None`. We ended up writing a custom binding though.