# With self hosting in Windows service, can I use two different IP addresses for configuring my endpoints?

Tags: c#, wcf, hosting

I have a WCF service in self hosted enviroment basically using windows service. Now we are planning to increase network adapters on the server so that it can listen on multiple IP addresses, Can I configure my wcf service in such a way that whatever IP address client calls from would resolve to same WCF service. Basically my question is Can I configure WCF service to listen to two/more different IP adreeses with Http protocol? If yes then how the configuration should be? How would I have to define my server config file?

Comment: Duplicate of [WCF listen base address anyip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434216/wcf-listen-base-address-anyip).

Comment: Thanks for link, just watend to check so using `Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8080/MyService"); host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServer), baseAddress);` would solve my issue?? can I add this to server config file like <baseAddresses> <add baseAddress="http://0.0.0.0:8080/MyService" /> <add baseAddress="net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8080/MyService" />  </baseAddresses> Please note I am not hosting it in IIS, I am hosting it in windows service...

Comment: It depends a bit on how you instantiate your ServiceHost (from code or from config), but yes, the "any" IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) means the host listens on all IPv4 address assigned to all NICs of the machine.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster, "any" in your comments means "0.0.0.0:8080" right?

Comment: @CodeCaster, one more question, Can we have one protocol e.g. HTTP listening on multiple IPAddress? As in this case if we are configuring multiple network adapters but all of them would be used in WCF service to listen to HTTP protocol.. I read on MSDN that one protocol can listen to only one address, may be I dont recall it exactly.. but had this doubt...

Comment: See [IPAddress.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any(v=vs.110).aspx). And yes you can process HTTP messages from multiple endpoints, the protocol is not bound to an IP.