# One WCF service listening to multiple addresses (config only)

Tags: wcf, windows-services, app-config

I have an existing Windows service (so no IIS) which hosts a WCF-service.

At this moment it is listening one address: http://xxx/service.svc.

And now I want it to ALSO listen to a second address: http://yyy/service.svc.

I can only modify the configuration, not the sources. The service is running under .NET Framework 4.5.2.

My configuration:

```
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="All" name="MyNamespace.MyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfig" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://xxx/service.svc"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
```

What I have tried so far:

- Added an extra base address. Then I get an exception: `This collection already contains an address with scheme http.`
- Duplicated the service-element and modify the base address. Exception: `A child element named 'service' with same key already exists at the same configuration scope.`
- If I change the name of both services: `Service 'MyNamespace.MyService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints.`
- If have read about and tried `serviceHostingEnvironment` (as suggested in [WCF service startup error "This collection already contains an address with scheme http"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561823/wcf-service-startup-error-this-collection-already-contains-an-address-with-sche)) but only adding that snippet in, does not help. Maybe that is a half step forward, but then I need the second half of that solution.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434216/wcf-listen-base-address-anyip) would give you some help.

Comment: [The msdn sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/multiple-endpoints-at-a-single-listenuri) demonstrates a service that hosts multiple endpoints at a single ListenUri.